# apply function TRUE/FALSE Ratios

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataframe with only TRUE/FALSE values

```
 tf <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(rep(TRUE,5),rep(FALSE,5)),10,10))
```

and I want to calculate the percentage of TRUE values for each column. Thus I wrote the following apply function, which however only returns an empty vector:

```
overlay <- apply(tf,2,function(x) sum(x == TRUE)/nrow(x))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x` inside your anonymous functions `function(x) sum(x == TRUE)/nrow(x)` is a vector corresponding to a certain row. Hence, it's not `nrow` what you need but `length`:

```
apply(tf, 2, function(x) sum(x == TRUE) / length(x))
```

On the other hand, you may achieve the same in a vectorized manner with

```
colMeans(tf)
#  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 
# 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know, that nrow does not work in this case! But I will use colMeans(tf) as it is so simple.

Answer (score 4):

This should be fast

```
colMeans(tf)
# V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 
#0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you used `nrow` but Check this:

```
overlay <- apply(tf,2,function(x) sum(x == TRUE)/length(x) * 100)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. I did not know that I cannot use nrow in this case.

Comment: @Mucteam Happy coding